# R: How can I fit a regression with constraints on the coefficients?

Tags: r, constraints, regression

I want to fit a regression model where the sum of b0 and b1 equal 1.

y = b0C + b1x       , where C is a constant.

Is there an easy way to do this? I read about the `glmc` package, but didn't understand how to specify the constraint.

Comment: so your model is `y = a + x`, where `a` is to be found? You can use simple optimization for this.

Comment: I think the model will degenerate to an intercept model. The OLS estimate of C is `mean(y - x)`

Comment: @DarrenTsai exactly. Perhaps the OP's objective is not OLS

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry! I misspecified the constraint:  the SUM of b0 and b1 equal 1

Answer (score 3):

You can use any R function for optimization. Suppose you want to fit your model to the `mtcars` (`mpg ~ hp`) dataset. First, we code the equation for the model:

```
# par1 is c
# par2 is b
lin_reg <- function(par,x){
  par[1]*par[2]+(1-par[2])*x
}
```

`b0` and `b1` add up to 1. Hence, you only need to find one of them. Next step is to provide an objective function. We will use the OLS objective:

```
objective <- function(par, y, x){
  sum((y-lin_reg(par,x))^2)
}
```

After that, we minimize the objective w.r.t to `par`:

```
nlm(f=objective,
    p=c(1,0.5),
    y=mtcars$mpg,
    x=mtcars$hp)
```

**Output**

```
$minimum
[1] 447.6743

# c and b
$estimate
[1] 28.176132  1.068226

$gradient
[1]  8.473213e-08 -1.314359e-05

$code
[1] 1

$iterations
[1] 10
```

Your model is equivalent to a linear regression with the OLS objective (two parameters with unconstrained values):

```
 > lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           hp  
   30.09886     -0.06823
```

Observe that `b1 = 1 - b0 = -0.06823`, the same result as in `lm`. You will get a different result if you make `b0` and `b1` strictly positive.

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at it is that you're solving a system of equations.

```
y = a*c + b*x , and  
a=1-b
```

(where c is known). So feed those to  `nleqslv` or `BBsolve` or `ktsolve` (all packages available at CRAN